# g++ links fine with old object files with old code

Tags: c++, linker, g++

base1.h

```
void base2::base22fun()
{
  cout<<"inside base2::base22fun()"<<endl;
}
```

base1.cpp

```
#include "base1.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
void base1::base1fun()
{
  cout<<"inside base1::base1fun()"<<endl;
}
```

base2.h

```
class base2
{
 public:


  virtual void base2fun();
};
```

base2.cpp

```
#include "base2.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

void base2::base2fun()
{
  cout<<"inside base2::base2fun()"<<endl;
}
```

derived.h

```
#include "base1.h"
#include "base2.h"

class derived : public base1, public base2
{
 public:
  virtual void base1fun();
  virtual void base2fun();
};
```

derived.cpp

```
#include "derived.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

void derived::base1fun()
{
  cout<<"inside  derived::base1fun"<<endl;
}

void derived::base2fun()
{
  cout<<"inside  derived::base2fun"<<endl;
}
```

global.cpp

```
#include "derived.h"

static derived d;
base1& b1=d;
base2& b2=d;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "base2.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  extern base2& b2;
  cout<<b2.base2fun();
 return 0;
}
```

I generated object file of all .cpp files using `g++ base1.cpp base2.cpp derived.cpp global.cpp main.cpp -c`

Then I linked them all, it worked fine.

Now I modified base2.h base2.cpp and main.cpp as follows

base2.h

```
class base2
{
 public:
  int padding;
  virtual void base22fun();
  virtual void base2fun();
};
```

base2.cpp

```
#include "base2.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;
void base2::base22fun()
{
  cout<<"inside base2::base22fun()"<<endl;
}

void base2::base2fun()
{
  cout<<"inside base2::base2fun()"<<endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "base2.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  extern base2& b2;
  cout<<b2.padding;
 return 0;
}
```

I then recompiled base2.cpp, derived.cpp and main.cpp

I didn't recompile global.cpp, and used the old object file[global.o], and g++ linked them and the executable executed. How is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is this surprising? Why do you think the linker would fail to link object files compiled at different times?

Comment: @user657267 The memory layout of `derived d` in global.o is according to old definition of `base2` , so it should not work when `base2` is modified. Please correct if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, learn to use a `makefile`. That way, you don't have to type so much...

The linker will succeed as long as the required global symbols are present - in this case, the constructor of the class and probably the vtable of the class. Your object takes up extra space after the recompile, so it will overwrite another variable. If you were to add:

```
static int x = 42;
```

after `static derived d;` - and not initialize `padding` in the constructor, you'd see `padding` printed as 42.

And all of this is "undefined behaviour". It is allowed to fail in any plausible way - format your hard-disk, start world war III, or "kind of work with subtle side-effects". Using a `makefile` with the relevant dependencies set so that you automatically recompile `objects.cpp` whenever `base2.h` changes would be the right thing to do.

Comment: it worked even when I tried to call  `base2::base22fun` from main. Does this work because there is only one vtable for `base2` ? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there should only be one vtable (for a given class)

Answer (score 0):

the object "static derived d;" is created when you run your exe. it has nothing to do with complie and link. so it worked.

Comment: But the SPACE allocated by the compiler is "smaller" than it should be after `padding` is added - because the compiler allocates the size at compile-time.

Comment: the SPACE is allocated when the exe is started.

Comment: Nope. Check the generated assembly file (-S in gcc/clang) - it will have something like `d: .zero 8` (or 4) - recompile with modified object, and the 8 (or 4) will change to 12 or 16 or something.

Comment: Unless you misunderstood what I meant, I do apologize, as it's not entirely clear - the SIZE of the object is determined at compile-time - the actual memory it occupies is of course allocated at the time the executable file is loaded. The key however is that the size is determined at compile-time, not at runtime, for the object.

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood.

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood. when in the compile-time, some param like this 'd: .zero 8' is a relative address .if the address of d is 0x000, the address of d.ispadding is 0x000:4 ,but the 0x000 is created when the exe is started. when compile-time the 0x000 is a symbol. so in global.o it is a symbol only, it has nothing to do with padding.

Comment: Right, there will be a reference to the address of `d` - but the size needed for `d` is X bytes, and X is calculated at the time the compiler generates global.o. The member variable called `padding` is indeed important here, since it changes the size of the variable `d`.

Comment: @MatsPetersson how to see size of objects in the object file?

Comment: are you sure this size of d is in global.o. i think it should be in drived.o

Comment: when d is created, it should call d's constructor function, and the function is in drived.o. so if it has the size X,it should be in drived.o.

Comment: I know because I have written a compiler as a hobby project, and worked with C compilers for the past 25 or so years... :) Seriously, how would derived.o know how many and where the derived objects are? What if you have a local variable that is allocated on the stack, how does the compiler know where the different objects are. If this is not clear, do ask a question and I'll try to write an answer, as it's only barely connected with this one. Even if we did `derived *d = new derived;` the size would be determined at compile time.

Comment: in my opinion,when we did 'derived *d = new derived;', the compiler do 'derived *d =(derived *)malloc(sizeof(derived)); d->derived::derived();'.so the key is 'sizeof(derived)'. you can see the function 'sizeof' how to work.